# Python's len() Big O notation for custom created class

Tags: python, class, big-o

Is the running time of   **__len__(self)**   of a custom created object, O(1) as is for the built-in types for the CPython implementation;

Comment: How long is a piece of string?  The big O for an unspecified function is unspecified.

Comment: A custom created class should implement its own `__len__` method, the time complexity of which certainly depends on the implementation of the custom method itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well for a built-in python object, they are O(1) because they keep track of their length which is accessed with __len__(). If the custom created object does this, or inherits from an object that does, then yes. It depends how it is implemented. I could put a loop in __len__() that does not take O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the built-in types just return **self.length**, where length is an updated value attached to the object